# There is in ListView the possibility of SetSelected like in ListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

my application have ListView and inside my foreach loop i am add files into my ListView and want the option to show the current file as marked, before using ListView i try ListBox and used SetSelected successfully.

i try  `listView.Items[listView.Items.Count - 1].Selected = true;` nut this marked all the files inside my ListView

Comment: Did you tried anything? Please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: Post a sample of the loop code you are using.  Are you setting the selected property on all items in the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are setting the selection outside the loop.  if you do it in the loop, you will see that all items are selected because the listview item count is increasing as you add items to the listview:

```
for (int i; i<someList.Count; i++)
{
    // Fill the listview here
}
listView.Items[listView.Items.Count - 1].Selected = true;
```

Comment: OK, thanks it's working but how can i see all the time the last item in my ListView ? currently i need to use the Vertical scroll and than i can see the last item marked

Comment: listView1.EnsureVisible(listView1.Items.Count - 1);

Answer (score 0):

U are probably set the `listView.Items[listView.Items.Count - 1].Selected = true;` wrongly as stated by John Koerner.
If you have a reason to always select the last item in loop, u can remove all the selection before select again.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        foreach (int index in listView1.SelectedIndices)
        {
            listView1.Items[index].Selected = false;
        }
        listView1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].Selected = true;
    }
```

or if multiple selection is not useful, u can set `listView1.MultiSelect = false;`